# How would I go about replacing everything in between multiple layers of parentheses?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to replace everything in between a set of parentheses in java using the replaceAll() method. The problem I'm running into is that in between the set of parentheses are another set so it looks like the following: (stuff here (more stuff) and more stuff) and using the regular expression: `\\(.*?\\)` doesn't work because it ends up only replacing part of it because of the nested parentheses. Any suggestions on a regex I could use to replace everything?

Comment: What output do you want?"(stuff here (more stuff) and more stuff)" to "(stuff here and more stuff)"?

Comment: I want to remove everything in () so if it were "stuff (stuff here (more stuff) and more stuff)" I'd get stuff and nothing else. Although for future reference it would also be helpful to do the other as well although I think I could do that by using substrings.

Comment: multiple layers of parentheses is not a matter of regex, since the languages is not regular

Comment: Alright then what could I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping round brackets like:

```
String data_message = "stuff(stuff here (more stuff) and more stuff)";
System.out.println(data_message.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", ""));
Output:
stuff
```

Comment: It's as per the specification from OP. OP didn't specified about your requirement.

Comment: I didn't think that would work but it did. I thought that would have removed everything from the string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no restriction on the nesting level and you're using "traditional" regexps, then the answer is, unfortunately, "no" (see, for example, the accepted answer for this question: [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)).

If you're ok with limited nesting or ok with making your regexp language-specific... well, check other answers to that question :)